# Certainty Equivalent of a Poisson distributed function.

Tags: exponential-function, poisson-distribution, utility

I am struggling with a calculation for my thesis and was wondering, whether you could assist me.

I have the following payoff function: $$X_i=N_i R-c,  N_i \sim \textrm{Poisson} (\lambda) $$
And the following exponential utility: $$u(x)\equiv\frac{1}{\rho}(1-e^{-\rho x})$$
My goal is to calculate the certainty equivalent: $CE_i\equiv u^{-1}(\mathbb E[u(X_i)])$, however my result $CE_i=\lambda R$ contradicts my source which comes up with $CE_i=\lambda u(R)$. Looking forward to any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that 
$$
u^{-1}(y)= -\frac{\log(1-\rho y)}{\rho},
$$
and that 
$$
E(U(X_i)) = \frac{1}{\rho}\left(1-e^{\rho c} E\left(e^{-\rho R N_i}\right) \right)  =\frac{1}{\rho}\left(1- e^{\rho c+\lambda(\exp({-\rho R})-1)} \right),
$$
where the expectation is recognized as the [moment generating function of $N_i$ at $-\rho R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). Inserting the latter into the former we get that
\begin{align}
u^{-1} \left( E(U(X_i))\right) &= -\frac{\log(1-\rho \frac{1}{\rho}\left(1- e^{\rho c+\lambda(\exp({-\rho R})-1)} \right))}{\rho} \\
&= -\frac{\rho c+\lambda(\exp({-\rho R})-1) )}{\rho} \\
&= -c +\lambda \left( \frac{1-e^{-\rho R}}{\rho} \right) \\
&= -c +\lambda u(R).
\end{align}
This would align with your source if they don't have any cost $c\in \mathbb{R}$ in their payoff function.

Comment: Hey Martin, I have a follow-up question: What happens to the moment generating function in the case below: $$ E(e^{- \rho R N_i M_i }) , N_i \sim Poisson (\lambda), M_i \sim Exponential (1/t, 1/t^2) $$

Comment: If N and M are independent then use tower property of expectations to condition on e.g. M. Search for moment generating function for compound Poisson to get an idea of what I mean.